# Load Error when requiring 'twitter-text' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to use the twitter-text-rb (https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb) in my Rails 3 app.

I installed it using bundler and my gemfile - seemingly successfully - but when I try and include its autolink function in my Application Helper, like this:

```
require 'twitter-text'
module ApplicationHelper
include Twitter::Autolink
end
```

I get this error in the browser when I try to load the root of the app:

> Routing Error
>   uninitialized constant Twitter::Autolink Try running rake routes for
>   more information on available routes.

I've followed these Troubleshooting Questions within the  [Ruby Gems manual](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/19#page105) but it doesn't seem to be either of the two likely issues that they suggest under "Why does require 'some_gem' fail?".

Here's the extract from when I followed their instructions from the root of my app using terminal:

```
manager$ gem list twitter-text

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

twitter-text (1.5.0)
manager$ ruby -rubygems -e 'require "twitter-text"'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- twitter-text (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from -e:1
manager$ gem contents --no-prefix twitter-text | grep lib
lib/twitter-text.rb
lib/twitter-text/autolink.rb
lib/twitter-text/deprecation.rb
lib/twitter-text/extractor.rb
lib/twitter-text/hit_highlighter.rb
lib/twitter-text/regex.rb
lib/twitter-text/rewriter.rb
lib/twitter-text/unicode.rb
lib/twitter-text/validation.rb
manager$ ruby -rubygems -e 'require "twitter-text"'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- twitter-text (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from -e:1
manager$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
manager$ gem env | grep 'RUBY EXECUTABLE'
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
```

I'm using and handful of other gems in the app and haven't run into similar problems before.

I'm at a loss as what to try next. I'm pretty new to Ruby/Rails (and programming in general for that matter!) so any help would be much appreciated.

thanks,

Matt

Comment: Adding it to your gemfile should automatically require it unless you use `require: false` in your Gemfile. Are you using rvm or anything?

Comment: @Beerlington - thanks for the advice. I didn't realise that the require wasn't necessary. However, I still think there's a problem with finding or loading the gem. When I remove the "require 'twitter-text'" from the ApplicationHelper, but keep "include Twitter::Autolink" in there, I get this error: "Routing Error

uninitialized constant Twitter::Autolink
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes." And when I do the test described above in the RubyGems Manual for the other gems I use (like Twitter, kaminari and friendly_id) I don't get similar errors. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Are you using rvm gem sets? Is twitter-text listed if you run 'bundle show' ?

Comment: No I'm not using rvm. And yes it is listed when I run 'bundle show'. Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now got this gem working and removed the Load Error (although I can't say for sure what went right).

I installed RVM and tried my app and the twitter_gem using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2.3. I was previously using the system default Ruby - 1.8.7 - and Rails 3.2.3. The gem was loaded correctly and worked perfectly.

So it seems like the problem was with the gem working on the earlier version of Ruby or RVM's gemsets helped the app to load the gem correctly.